# Language & Region Setting doesn't right

Tags: release-loki

I'm using Elementary OS 0.4 live on USB stick and don't know if "Formats" in "Language & Region" setting is correct (it's all in Russian).

It's English by default, but the "Formats" sections is Russian (also by default). I changed to different language (Vietnamese in my case) and "Formats" drop-down list appeared correctly, but still has big blue check on English.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you change it to something else, like english?

Comment: @Gabriel It's English by default, but the "Formats" sections is Russian (also by default). I changed to different language (Vietnamese in my case) and "Formats" drop-down list appeared correctly, but still has big blue check on English.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [**bug**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1593339) i also noticed on liveUSB.
It's reported and confirmed but not fixed. If this bug affects you so please register on launchpad and go to [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1593339/+affectsmetoo). 
By the way, after installation everthing is ok and you can change your language and formats.